# my app crash when it return from background because of watchdog

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, watchdog, springboard

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL) Exception Codes:
> 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note:
> EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code
> 0x8badf00d Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-update watchdog
> transgression: application<*cbundlename*>:354 exhausted real (wall
> clock) time allowance of 10.00 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Foreground
> | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-update |
> WatchdogVisibility: Background | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed
> total CPU time (seconds): 9.630 (user 9.630, system 0.000), 6% CPU", |
> "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 1.088, 1% CPU" | ) Triggered
> by Thread:  0

this is happening sometime to CLIENT , I almost can't reproduce this and I do not get any crashes
neither in Xcode organiser nor in Crashlytics
I can just get the logs from the device -> setting-> privacy-> analytics
I have worked very hard to remove all memory leaks and to clean the main thread as I can move the task to `DispatchQueue.background`
also, I have cleaned logic from `AppDelegate` functions
and **it still happens.**

Please advise!

Comment: What code are you executing when the application comes back to the foreground?

Comment: Login back to websoket , set timer to call that happen every 30 min

Comment: You could try disabling Watchdog? After all, isn't it supposed to help you debug processes that take too long? So technically, you don't need it in production ap..

Answer (score 1):

Code 0x8badf00d is the error code that the watchdog raises when an application takes too long to launch or terminate.

Usually, it means you either have an infinite loop somewhere, or you are waiting for network IO on the main thread. There's also the possibility that the user is force-quitting the application.

You can refer https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1693/_index.html
apple's reference document for more details and the possible ways to handle this scenario in your project.

Comment: all my networking warped in  DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {}